# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'transform' in true

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am getting this error when i populate the user and movie field in my review model.
error is `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'transform' in true`

```
reviewSchema.pre(/^find/,function(next){
    this.populate({  
        path:'user',
        select:'name'
    }).populate({
        path:'movie',
        select:'name'
    })
    next();
})
```

the populate code is working fine only for `user` but not for `movie`
i.e. if i remove the populate code of movie then i get the populated result of user in output
but for the above code it gives error
My reviewSchema Code

```
const reviewSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    review:{
        type:String,
        required:['true','blank space not allowed'],
        trim:true
    },
    rating:{
        type:Number,
        max:5,
        min:1
    },
    user:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref:'movieUsers',
        required:[true,'review must have a user']
    },
    movie:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref:'movies',
        required:[true,'review must belong to a movie']
    }
});
```

Comment: This isn't driver code, you are missing the mongoose tag.

Comment: thanks for that. i used it now. please tell me what i do???